# error in datetime when a function is repeated

Tags: python, datetime

I'm building a time division selector, i.e., if the actual time is 21h34 and I choose a 3 minutes division, it will return 21h33 (it always start from the pure hour - in this case 21h00, and returns the low closest value). If the time is 14h17, it will return 14h16.

The following code was implemented to solve the problem:

```
import datetime


def last_time(interval):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    last_time = now.replace(microsecond=0,second=0,minute=0)
    while True:
        if((last_time < now) & (now < last_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds = interval))):
            return last_time,(last_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds = interval)), \
        ((last_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds = interval)) - now).total_seconds()
            break
        last_time = last_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds = interval)
```

and to execute the function we do:

```
last_time, next_time, delta = last_time(180) #in GMT
```

If I run the function only once, it will work without any problem. However, if I run it again, it returns the following error:

```
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable
```

Comment: You've overwritten the function with your local variable. Give it a different name.

Comment: Note also, the function probably doesn't do what you meant, as you used `&` where you should have used `and`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting a `TypeError` is because `last_time` is both a function *and* a variable; when you run the line `last_time, next_time, delta = last_time(180) #in GMT`, you are basically overwriting the function with the `datetime.datetime` object returned.

Thankfully, the solution is a quick fix, just change either the variable name or the function name, and the problem will stop!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Make sure to make this the accepted answer by pressing the tick next to this answer if it helped you!